# How can I do an form price with jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have this form:

```
 <2>First Item</h2>
 <input type="checkbox" name="item[1][]" value="10"> Buy for 10 dollars.
 <input type="checkbox" name="item[1][]" value="20"> Buy for 20 dollars.
 <input type="checkbox" name="item[1][]" value="30"> Buy for 30 dollars.  
 <h2>Secound Item</h2>
 <input type="checkbox" name="item[2][]" value="10"> Buy for 10 dollars.
 <input type="checkbox" name="item[2][]" value="20"> Buy for 20 dollars.
 <input type="checkbox" name="item[2][]" value="30"> Buy for 30 dollars.
```

I would like to send to my data.php.

```
 $price_one = $POST['item[1][]']; //Here get the price 
 $price_two = $POST['item[3][]']; //Here get the price
```

I dont really know if I can set the value direct to HTML, because if user change like:

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="item[1][]" value="1"> Buy for 10 dollars.
```

It will send to the wrong value to my data.php.

What is the best and safe way to do this with jquery and ajax?

Comment: not clear ...........

Comment: please offer specifics

Comment: The best way to do this is server-sided. The DOM contains only an ID-referens to the actuall item, so even if they edit the price, you will get the price from the server.

Comment: Oh, and how can I know the selected box and the respective price on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am taking a whacky guess here and shooting in the dark. I am guessing you don't want price tampering through your HTML form. From some of the suggestions you can do something like this:

1. Create a set list of prices that are acceptable and give each an id (if they tamper and change they still pay an acceptable price from the list you set. So you can handle that argument elsewhere)
2. Set the price id as the checkbox value and once the id matches something process it, if not return an error

Here is some visuals:

```
//storage structure
id | price
------------
1  | 10
2  | 20
3  | 30
```

HTML Form:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1"> Buy for 10 dollars.
<input type="checkbox" value="2"> Buy for 20 dollars.
<input type="checkbox" value="3"> Buy for 30 dollars.
```

Although based on what you need radio buttons may work out better instead of checkboxes

UPDATE: Based on question update I see the problem a bit more clearly, however even if the price is tampered with you can always map the items to possible prices so that any tampering can be detected. Using Javascript and JQuery can only give you some form of security but not in my opinion. Server side validation is better for this.

Comment: Ohh Thanks. How can I do the server side validation in this case?

Comment: That's a separate question but basically when the data is received before storing it or processing a payment just do some lookups to be sure that the data is acceptable, accurate etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign an id to each checkbox. The id's would allow you to access them individually:

Buy for 10 dollars.

document.getElementById("cb10")...

It is not clear exactly what you want to do, but since the 'Buy for x dollars' elements have no id, you could use nextSibling:

var x = document.getElementById("cb10").nextSibling.innerHTML;

After that statement, the value of x is 'Buy for 10 dollars'.

To determine whether the user checked the box use:

document.getElementById("cb10").checked

Comment: You still should assign an id to the checkboxes. That way you can access each one and tell if it is checked.